# How To Write A Sql query By Using Passing parameters in Sql

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have 4 Parameters which are passing Dynamically in sql query, i want to be filter data with that parameters in where condition and atleast one parameter should pass the value and rest are may be null

Parameters are: `@Orderstatusid`,`@paymentStatusid`,`@today`,`@fromdate`,`@todate`

Comment: Have you even tried looking online for this?  These are fairly fundamental aspects of SQL Server: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2981/using-parameters-for-sql-server-queries-and-stored-procedures/

Comment: Yes i have tried i have got only single parameter passing examples

Comment: i have been trying to pass multiple parameters which means data should be fetch even if one parameter pass the value or all values

Comment: You are looking for a catch-all query. [Read this SO post.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31933431/sql-server-2008-r2-prepare-dynamic-where-clause/31933677#31933677) It's not an exact duplicate so I will not mark it as one but it will give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set every input parameter intially to NULL and then override it by passing the necessary parameter.

```
ALTER PROC YOUR_PROCEDURE_NAME
    (@Orderstatusid INT = NULL
     ,@paymentStatusid INT = NULL
     ,@today DATE = NULL
     ,@fromdate DATE = NULL
     ,@todate DATE = NULL
     )
AS
BEGIN
        -- YOUR CODE HERE....
        -- YOUR WHERE CLAUSE SHOULD HAVE
         Orderstatusid =    @Orderstatusid OR
         paymentStatusid = @paymentStatusid OR
         today = @today OR
         fromdate = @fromdate OR
         todate = @todate



END
GO

You can call your sp like below:

EXEC YOUR_PROCEDURE_NAME @Orderstatusid = '101'
OR
EXEC YOUR_PROCEDURE_NAME @today = 'YOUR_DATE'
...
```

Comment: @saikrishna - Did you try this solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution.

```
declare @whereCondition varchar(max)
declare @sql varchar(max) 

if (@Orderstatusid is not null)
set @whereCondition = 'Orderstatusid = ' + @Orderstatusid

if (@paymentStatusid is not null)
begin
if(@whereCondition !='')
begin
    set @whereCondition = @whereCondition +' and paymentStatusid = ' + @paymentStatusid --use and/or  as per your requirement
end
else
begin 
    set @whereCondition = ' paymentStatusid = ' + @paymentStatusid
end
end

-------write if condition for all cases

set @sql= 'select * from TABLENAME where ' + @whereCondition

exec @sql
```